# How to generate .pt weight file without the confidence score and labels in YOLOv5

Tags: python, user-interface, yolo, yolov5

In Yolov5 .pt file should generate without labels and confidence score, I have done changes in detect.py but while doing GUI inference I am not able to remove the labels and confidence score I just want to plot bounding boxes.

Comment: Please post the code to the extent you have tried. In that way you will get an answer faster

Answer (score 1):

You needn't change `detect.py` for anything at all.

For GUI inference, just mention `--hide-conf` and `--hide-labels` while running the python detect.py script.

For instance,

> `!python detect.py [other args] --hide-conf --hide-labels --line-thickness 1`

`--line-thickness 1` argument is for further **thinning** of bounding box **border lines** so as to improve GUI

For more args related adjustments, refer to the last section of [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py)